# multiple functions (or instances of the same function?) in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to make an animatronic shooting gallery using 2 arduinos, and maybe a servo controller. Arduino 1 handles all the guns and targets and sends single byte commands to the computer (over com3) for each target hit (max 30 targets).

The Python program needs to receive this information, and play audio and read a file containing motor position and time information, and send out the single-byte motor position codes to Arduino 2 on com4 (max 256 motors), and possibly a servo controller on com 5, but only if I get things working with simple on/off motors/solenoids, and bi-directional motors.

Each target hit may activate a routine lasting several seconds. I have no problem getting python to play one file, and send out motor position data to several motors that are working together, but I can't figure out a way to get multiple characters (each character is a group of motors working synchronously with each other) running through separate routines simultaneously.

The plan was to create a single Bot() class, and make each character an instance of that class, then call a function within them that would run the routine when their respective targets are hit.

I've looked at multithreading, but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for. I am fairly new to Python and programming in general, and I don't want to go down the wrong path if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: It's tough to tell what you are asking, but you almost certainly want to make a class and make each "target" its own instance.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.

Comment: The main thing I need to know is how to get multiple methods running simultaneously and sending data to the serial port. I'm thinking about using multiprocessing and queues, but If there is a simpler solution, I'd rather use that.

Comment: I guess the first question is, do you actually need them running simultaneously? Why not just have a big "game loop" that steps through each target one at a time?

Comment: That might work. The main page for tkSnack says:

"Multiple simultaneous playback and recording threads (system dependent)."

If I can figure that out, it might work. I can't find any mention of how to implement this feature in the manual, though.